# Bare minimum page to get _spPageContextInfo loaded

Tags: sitepages

I would like to know what is the minimum markup a SharePoint hosted aspx content page must have to get _spPageContextInfo loaded.

I plan to develop an angularjs SPA hosted on SharePoint site. I would like to avoid, if possible, master pages, web part pages and application pages. I plan to use client side object model and OData.

I've seen this post:

[Can't use _spPageContextInfo](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113227/cant-use-sppagecontextinfo)

But it's a web part page.

I've also seen this other post:

http://sharepoint.aspcode.net/view/635399286724222582117090/napa-app-sppagecontextinfo-is-not-defined

suggesting you just need script manager in a form, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Thank you, after a day of searching your answer was the one that worked.

Comment: @Carol, I'm glad my answer helped you. Incidentally, you posted your comment on the question, better post your comment on the answer, because it refers to the answer and not to the question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ironically, after finishing the SPA aplication using a web part page, I found the bare minimum page to get _spPageContextInfo loaded:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ Page language="C#" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" 
     Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" 
     Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<html>
<head> 
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <SharePoint:FormDigest ID="FormDigest1" runat="server"></SharePoint:FormDigest>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to use JSOM you will also need to load some javascript files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ Page language="C#" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" 
     Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" 
     Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
    <script src="/_layouts/1033/init.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/sp.core.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/sp.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <SharePoint:FormDigest ID="FormDigest1" runat="server"></SharePoint:FormDigest>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Replace version 14 with 15 to get it to work with SP 2013