# SP2013 javascript client object model - get server time

Tags: javascript, date-time, jsom

My client machine and server machine has time offset of 2:30 hours. So when I try to retrieve Date/Time field using JSOM, it gives time according to offset.

```
oListItem.get_item("Modified");
```

So how to get server time even when creating `new Date()` object. Can it be acheived by `new SP.ClientContext.get_current().get_web().get_regionalSettings()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you should get the site's `TimeZone` first and then convert your `DateTime` accordingly.

```
function getTimeZoneAndServerDateTime() {

    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var timeZone = web.get_regionalSettings().get_timeZone();
    context.load(timeZone);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
    function onSucceeded() {
        var info = timeZone.get_information();
        var offset = (info.get_bias() + info.get_daylightBias()) / 60.0;
        var serverDateTimeNow = new Date(new Date().getTime() - offset * 3600 * 1000).toISOString();
        console.log("serverDateTimeNow: " + serverDateTimeNow);
    },
     Failure
    );

}

function Failure() {
    alert("error");
}
```

Also `Vadim Gremyachev` has posted nice answer here at [sharepoint designer - get current server datetime through javascript REST](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121633/sharepoint-designer-get-current-server-datetime-through-javascript-rest)

Comment: Thanks. That works fine for retrieving Server Date. But how to save the date/time in server date/time format ?

Comment: Where do you want to save date values? In some list column? Also keep in mind that sharepoint stores date in utc format.

Comment: Yes.There is an editable Date/Time Column which I have to set with user editable date.

Comment: This answer is wrong. If the site is in a time zone that has DST, it will only produce the correct result during the DST part of the year.

Comment: @JLRishe Is that because the daylightBias will always return a value even if DST is not active?

Comment: @Dinerdo Yes, that's correct. `get_bias` returns the size of that region's DST offset regardless of whether they are currently in DST or not. My answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/229917/14016) shows that SharePoint actually provides a way to directly retrieve a site's local time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the accepted answer but it seems to give wrong time. I found [this post](http://sadomovalex.blogspot.sg/2015/05/get-sharepoint-current-datetime-in.html) which explains a better way and it seems to work for me always.

You use `_spPageContextInfo.clientServerTimeDelta` to get the time delta and then add that to current date time.

```
var currentServerDateTime = new Date(new Date().getTime() + _spPageContextInfo.clientServerTimeDelta);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
var sysDateTime = new Date("<%= System.DateTime.Now %>");
```

You need to connect your site through COM and then perform this one. May be this can help you

Comment: He needs a JavaScript/ECMA solution. I don't think your solution wil work that way.:)

Comment: It should work in Javascript also..!!

Comment: The `<%= System.DateTime.Now %>` isn't JavaScript.