# SharePoint Online, Stripped down .aspx, requirements to access _spPageContextInfo

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

What is requirements to access the `_spPageContextInfo` object from a blank `.aspx` page or `.html` in SharePoint Online?

I have a document library with a blank aspx-page and in that page I would like to access `userId` and some url's

So basically the online version of this previous [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116359/bare-minimum-page-to-get-sppagecontextinfo-loaded)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the same code from the other [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116359/bare-minimum-page-to-get-sppagecontextinfo-loaded) you mentioned?

You can use the REST api(or JSOM) to get the user id and pretty much anything you are looking for.

```
/_api/Web/CurrentUser?$select=Id
```