# _sppagecontextinfo is not defined in SharePoint master page

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-masterpage, spurl

I am creating a custom master page where I have used `_sppagecontextinfo.webabsoluteurl` but I am getting _sppagecontextinfo as undefined.

What is work around to get it in master page?

Comment: it should be `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl`, can you check ?

Comment: It is probably just a typo.  The property you want to use is  _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl. JavaScript is case sensitive

Answer (score 3):

2 things to check.

1) You made a typo, instead of `_sppagecontextinfo.webabsoluteurl` , it should be `spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl`. If its still undefined, ensure step 2

2) Ensure that `formdigest` is present in the master page as below:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderFormDigest" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server" />
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Reference - [Bare minimum necessary to get _spPageContextInfo](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116359/bare-minimum-page-to-get-sppagecontextinfo-loaded)

Comment: 1st is  not right becuase i'm still getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'webAbsoluteUrl' of undefined` .let me try 2nd option

Comment: `SharePoint:FormDigest`  is already there in master page.

Comment: can you run the code after this `SharePoint:FormDigest` tag ? Ensure that this tag is present at the top just after `<body>` tag. Also check the link in the answer for the namespace `<%@ Page language="C#" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" 
     Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" 
     Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>`