# Get custom html page to load _spPageContextInfo on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I made a custom html page that I changed to be an aspx page. I'm trying to use _spPageContextInfo, but it's saying it's undefined. I've looked at the [Bare Minimum Page to Get _spPageContextINfo loaded](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116359/bare-minimum-page-to-get-sppagecontextinfo-loaded), but it doesn't work for SharePoint **Online**. There's no more init.js and core.js etc.

What do tags/lines do I need to add to get it to work for SharePoint **Online**.

Comment: Are you using the "classic" experience or the "modern" experience?

Answer (score 0):

@A.h. Laverty,

I tried below aspx code on my SP online and it has `_spPageContextInfo`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register tagprefix="SharePoint" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>

<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="default" runat="server"/>
</head>

<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server" id="FormDigest1" />
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Test Result:

[image]

BR